# TOMCAT server becomes very slow after advancing time of system

Tags: java, tomcat

We are creating a test automation framework for web application. For Test scenarios including the Scheduled jobs, we need to advance the time to let the jobs triggered, But this is making the server (TOMCAT) very slow. What could be the reason and solution?

Comment: I don't like the idea of hacking the server's time.  Could you use a mock object instead?

Comment: Thanks Tim. Point is to see whether the jobs get triggered correctly or not. If we mocking the scheduled object and execute it, then it will do, But then that is not the point.